# Implementing chroot directory for sftp users

Tags: openssh

I am running OpenSSH64 on a Windows 2012 environment. OpenSSH64 is running and I can access the server. I have modified the `sshd_config` file with no success.

I have made the following changes:

```
Subsystem sftp C:\OpenSSH-Win64\sftp-server.exe 

Match User sftponly-user 
X11Forwarding no 
AllowTcpForwarding no 
ForceCommand internal-sftp 
ChrootDirectory %h
```

I have also tried

```
ChrootDirectory C:\User_Specific_Directory\
```

We are trying to generate logs to verify that the changes we make in the `sshd_config` file are being applied.  However, we receive the following error in the log:

```
3784 11:00:17 087 error: accept: The operation completed successfully.
```

Does anyone have a working example of `chrooting` a user to a specific directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openSSH connection reset by peer](http://superuser.com/questions/990935/openssh-connection-reset-by-peer) -- something similar will work on windows too

Answer (score 0):

This feature has not been implemented in OpenSSH for Windows (basically because it's hard): https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/190

Comment: FYI, support was added in v7.7.0.0 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration#chrootdirectory-support-added-in-v7700)

Answer (score 0):

Default OpenSSH config file location: **C:\ProgramData\ssh**

File name: **ssh_config**

```
Match User <windows_login_user_name>
    ChrootDirectory C:\0-Websites\myapp.com
    X11Forwarding no
    PermitTTY no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand sftp-server.exe
```

NOTE: All user name should be lower case.