# bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/www"

Tags: ssh, debian, sftp, chmod, sshd

I am getting following error in `auth.log` when trying to connect to site using SFTP.

> fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/var/www"

`ls -ld` of this directory shows this:

> drwxrwxr-x 4 root sftponly 4096 Aug 12 04:05 /var/www/

As you can see I have given full permission to group `sftponly`. The user through which I am connecting to SFTP is `mysftpuser` which is part of `sftponly` group.

If I do following then I can connect but cannot rename, edit, delete, overwrite any file or folder inside `www`

> sudo chmod 755 /var/www/

Here's my `sshd_config` setting

> Match group sftponly
>   ChrootDirectory /var/www
>   X11Forwarding no
>   AllowTcpForwarding no
>   ForceCommand internal-sftp

So in short `sudo chmod 755 /var/www/` allows me to connect but only in READ only mode. `sudo chmod 775 /var/www/` doesn't even allow me to connect.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Anyone has a suggestion? I have been trying for hours to fix this issue but no luck?  I created a new dir inside `/var/www` but it has the same issue. Even if I give 777 permission on `/var/www` then I cannot connect to SFTP. It will only connect if `/var/www/` has 755 permission but then it won't let me delete, rename etc.

Comment: sftponly probably have less permissions on child files and  directories, then on /var/www itself. If changing modes recursively is an option, that's your next step: `chmod -R 775 /var/www`.

Comment: I have already done this and it didn't solve the problem. Even if I give full permissions 777, I cannot connect.

Comment: Frank, you don't need other users to have full permissions (77**7**), you need users of `sftponly` group to have read, write, and optional - to execute all enclosed files and folders. You achieve that by: `chmod -R 775 /var/www`, and by making this group owner of child files and directories: `chown -R root:sftponly /var/www`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [openSSH connection reset by peer](https://superuser.com/questions/990935/openssh-connection-reset-by-peer)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the commands you need:

```
usermod -d /var/www/ sftponly
usermod -s /sbin/nologin sftponly
usermod -s /bin/false sftponly
```

After this best way to give permissions for any user to any folder is ACL:

```
setfacl -Rm "u:sftponly:rwx" /var/www/
setfacl -Rdm "u:sftponly:rwx" /var/www/
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your permissions are too permissive for SFTP. You will need to create a folder for the user and let him access it with 0700 permissions or even more restrictive than that.

See this question's answer for more info 
[Server Fault Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/416459/file-directory-permissions-for-sftp-user)